# Global Header file Node.js & Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I feel like the question is simple, and I'm surprised I haven't been able to find an answer, since I'm sure it's been asked before.

I am using node.js and express.js, and all I want to do is code out a single static header.html file that is included on every page. This file would have all the meta-tags and css file includes, and etc etc etc.

So when my server gets a request for website.com/blog/blog-post-3, it will
 1. Load my header.html file
 2. Load the content from the actual content.html file

It's the same concept as the `<?php include file.html ?>`....

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this has been asked before!! XD

Comment: Are you using any pre-processor? (Pug, etc)

Comment: Nope! I'm not using any pre-processor!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :-

At node server:-

```
var http = require('http');
var read =  require('fs').readFileSync;

http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
    res.end(new String(read('./headers.html')).replace('<my-content></my-content>',read('./content.html')));
}).listen(4000)
```

Headers.html:-

```
<html>
<!--custom css links here-->

<my-content></my-content>
<!-- custom scripts -->
</html>
```

Content.html:-

```
<body>Temp</body>
```

Comment: This seems like an approach that might work, but maybe isn't the intended use of `res.setHEader()`. I'll check it out, but I'm not sure if I'll choose this approach.

Comment: use some frameworks which provide template functionality then , like angular

Answer (score 1):

The way I've been doing it in my own app is to use a view engine that supports includes. I've been using Jade, which is now called Pug.

https://pugjs.org

With this approach you would wire up your Express app to serve your views via routes. Basically this involves setting the directory in which your views are kept, setting the view engine (Jade in my example) and defining a URL route whose response renders a view. Then in your view you would be able to define whatever include(s) you need.

Some example code (may not be complete but should give the general idea):

app.js

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

views/index.jade - main view

```
doctype html
html
  head
    include includes/head.jade
  body
    ...
```

views/includes/head.jade - include

```
link(href='index.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
...
```

Comment: I will have to read about this today and let you know. Seems like a decent way to go. Bummed I have to use another lib though...